# Can I translate an ASMX webservice with c# codebehind in PHP or node.js?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, web-services, mono

I have an ASMX webservice which uses a c# file with the codebehind attribute but I don't want to run things on windows server and using mono ( http://www.mono-project.com/ ) doesn't seem like the best solution for the long-term. Is there a way to translate that to PHP, node.js or something that will run on the linux server natively?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by completely rewriting the service in PHP script. If you want to mimic the old service as closely as possible, you'll have to use the SOAP protocol.

See also http://www.sitepoint.com/series/creating-web-services-with-php-and-soap/ for more about implementing SOAP services with PHP.

There's also an example on CodeProject with some interesting code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272657/Write-Enhanced-SOAP-Webservices-with-PHP

And another one, with detailed explanation also, on O'Reilly: http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2007/07/26/php-web-services.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the resources, it really seems that it's the way to go, maybe I should add a new question but I'll ask here also, is there a way to use the C# app in PHP soap service? I am converting videos to arrays of image frames and I think PHP would be too slow for that.

Comment: You mean you want to call C# code from your PHP service? Or do you mean you want a C# client to call your PHP service? (And yes it would be best to create a new question for that :-))

Comment: I want to serve the output of the C# code through the PHP service, I'll add a new question, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I managed to actually rewrite the code in PHP and it works great, didn't use a SOAP service after all because I didn't actually needed it with this approach. Thank you for the help.